# struggling with XML namespace nodes query

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm struggling to get my head around XML namespace query when using XML nodes - I've read other similar questions here and an article [here](http://marcanton.io/blog/the-cheaters-guide-to-mastering-xquery-on-sql-server-part-1/) but cannot apply this to my specific query.

I have a larger version of this sample XML:

```
SELECT CAST('<Navigator clsid="{ABF8EB05-610D-11D3-A53E-684F745C}">
  <Version>7</Version>
  <NavigatorNodes clsid="{0484ACB1-78F5-48D7-A26B-3A0ACD3A5F91}">
    <NavigatorNode clsid="{59AB61BD-7833-4954-94C2-B6D737E3DD6F}">
      <Indent>0</Indent>
      <Caption>Contact</Caption>
      <Selected>0</Selected>
      <ViewType>0</ViewType>
      <ViewSubType>0</ViewSubType>
      <ShowTotals>0</ShowTotals>
      <RowHeight>0</RowHeight>
      <Complement>0</Complement>
      <FreezeFirst>0</FreezeFirst>
      <a1:QueryFilter xmlns:a2="http://www.ascenttechnology.co.uk/schemas/entities" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/21/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a1="http://www.ascenttechnology.co.uk/schemas/services" Type="QueryFilter">
        <entity_name>Contact</entity_name>
        <relationship_name />
        <relationship_from_entity_name />
        <a1:ColumnInfoCollection Type="ColumnInfoCollection" AscentCollection="true">
          <__vers>1</__vers>
          <IgnoreMissingItem>0</IgnoreMissingItem>
          <ReadOnly>0</ReadOnly>
          <AllowNulls>0</AllowNulls>
          <a1:ColumnInfo Type="ColumnInfo">
            <attribute_name>state</attribute_name>
            <width>0</width>
          </a1:ColumnInfo>
          <a1:ColumnInfo Type="ColumnInfo">
            <attribute_name>current_address_suffix</attribute_name>
            <width>0</width>
          </a1:ColumnInfo>
        </a1:ColumnInfoCollection>
        <a1:SurveyColumnInfoCollection Type="AttributeInfoCollection" AscentCollection="true">
          <__vers>1</__vers>
          <IgnoreMissingItem>0</IgnoreMissingItem>
          <ReadOnly>0</ReadOnly>
          <AllowNulls>0</AllowNulls>
        </a1:SurveyColumnInfoCollection>
        <a1:WorkflowColumnInfoCollection Type="AttributeInfoCollection" AscentCollection="true">
          <__vers>1</__vers>
          <IgnoreMissingItem>0</IgnoreMissingItem>
          <ReadOnly>0</ReadOnly>
          <AllowNulls>0</AllowNulls>
        </a1:WorkflowColumnInfoCollection>
        <a1:ConditionCollection Type="ConditionCollection" AscentCollection="true">
          <__vers>1</__vers>
          <IgnoreMissingItem>0</IgnoreMissingItem>
          <ReadOnly>0</ReadOnly>
          <AllowNulls>0</AllowNulls>
          <a1:Condition Type="Condition">
            <attribute_name>class</attribute_name>
            <description1 />
            <description2 />
            <attribute_id>0</attribute_id>
            <not>0</not>
            <operator>28</operator>
            <value1>1</value1>
            <value2 xsi:nil="true" />
            <indent_level>0</indent_level>
            <value1_is_reference>0</value1_is_reference>
            <value2_is_reference>0</value2_is_reference>
          </a1:Condition>
          <a1:Condition Type="Condition">
            <attribute_name>do_not_mail</attribute_name>
            <description1 />
            <description2 />
            <attribute_id>0</attribute_id>
            <not>0</not>
            <operator>0</operator>
            <value1>True</value1>
            <value2 xsi:nil="true" />
            <indent_level>0</indent_level>
            <value1_is_reference>0</value1_is_reference>
            <value2_is_reference>0</value2_is_reference>
          </a1:Condition>
          <a1:Condition Type="Condition">
            <attribute_name>gone_away</attribute_name>
            <description1 />
            <description2 />
            <attribute_id>0</attribute_id>
            <not>0</not>
            <operator>0</operator>
            <value1>True</value1>
            <value2 xsi:nil="true" />
            <indent_level>0</indent_level>
            <value1_is_reference>0</value1_is_reference>
            <value2_is_reference>0</value2_is_reference>
          </a1:Condition>
          <a1:Condition Type="Condition">
            <attribute_name>dp_opt_out</attribute_name>
            <description1 />
            <description2 />
            <attribute_id>0</attribute_id>
            <not>0</not>
            <operator>0</operator>
            <value1>True</value1>
            <value2 xsi:nil="true" />
            <indent_level>0</indent_level>
            <value1_is_reference>0</value1_is_reference>
            <value2_is_reference>0</value2_is_reference>
          </a1:Condition>
          <a1:Condition Type="Condition">
            <attribute_name>deceased</attribute_name>
            <description1 />
            <description2 />
            <attribute_id>0</attribute_id>
            <not>0</not>
            <operator>0</operator>
            <value1>True</value1>
            <value2 xsi:nil="true" />
            <indent_level>0</indent_level>
            <value1_is_reference>0</value1_is_reference>
            <value2_is_reference>0</value2_is_reference>
          </a1:Condition>
          <a1:Condition Type="Condition">
            <attribute_name>deleted</attribute_name>
            <description1 />
            <description2 />
            <attribute_id>0</attribute_id>
            <not>0</not>
            <operator>0</operator>
            <value1>True</value1>
            <value2 xsi:nil="true" />
            <indent_level>0</indent_level>
            <value1_is_reference>0</value1_is_reference>
            <value2_is_reference>0</value2_is_reference>
          </a1:Condition>
          <a1:Condition Type="Condition">
            <attribute_name>Date_Of_Birth</attribute_name>
            <description1 />
            <description2 />
            <attribute_id>0</attribute_id>
            <not>0</not>
            <operator>19</operator>
            <value1>2010-06-23T::.+:</value1>
            <value2 xsi:nil="true" />
            <indent_level>0</indent_level>
            <value1_is_reference>0</value1_is_reference>
            <value2_is_reference>0</value2_is_reference>
          </a1:Condition>
          <a1:Condition Type="Condition">
            <attribute_name>home_address1</attribute_name>
            <description1 />
            <description2 />
            <attribute_id>0</attribute_id>
            <not>0</not>
            <operator>26</operator>
            <value1 xsi:nil="true" />
            <value2 xsi:nil="true" />
            <indent_level>0</indent_level>
            <value1_is_reference>0</value1_is_reference>
            <value2_is_reference>0</value2_is_reference>
          </a1:Condition>
          <a1:Condition Type="Condition">
            <attribute_name>home_postcode</attribute_name>
            <description1 />
            <description2 />
            <attribute_id>0</attribute_id>
            <not>0</not>
            <operator>26</operator>
            <value1 xsi:nil="true" />
            <value2 xsi:nil="true" />
            <indent_level>1</indent_level>
            <value1_is_reference>0</value1_is_reference>
            <value2_is_reference>0</value2_is_reference>
          </a1:Condition>
          <a1:Condition Type="Condition">
            <attribute_name>home_address1</attribute_name>
            <description1 />
            <description2 />
            <attribute_id>0</attribute_id>
            <not>0</not>
            <operator>0</operator>
            <value1 />
            <value2 xsi:nil="true" />
            <indent_level>0</indent_level>
            <value1_is_reference>0</value1_is_reference>
            <value2_is_reference>0</value2_is_reference>
          </a1:Condition>
          <a1:Condition Type="Condition">
            <attribute_name>home_postcode</attribute_name>
            <description1 />
            <description2 />
            <attribute_id>0</attribute_id>
            <not>0</not>
            <operator>0</operator>
            <value1 />
            <value2 xsi:nil="true" />
            <indent_level>1</indent_level>
            <value1_is_reference>0</value1_is_reference>
            <value2_is_reference>0</value2_is_reference>
          </a1:Condition>
        </a1:ConditionCollection>
        <a1:OrderByCollection Type="OrderByCollection" AscentCollection="true">
          <__vers>1</__vers>
          <IgnoreMissingItem>0</IgnoreMissingItem>
          <ReadOnly>0</ReadOnly>
          <AllowNulls>0</AllowNulls>
        </a1:OrderByCollection>
        <SelectedArticles xsi:nil="true" />
        <groupby_field_name />
        <reporting_currency>52</reporting_currency>
        <Negate_Filter>0</Negate_Filter>
        <Survey_Id>----</Survey_Id>
        <Survey_Name xsi:nil="true" />
        <Workflow_Id>----</Workflow_Id>
        <Workflow_Name xsi:nil="true" />
        <XPath>0</XPath>
        <locale>0</locale>
      </a1:QueryFilter>
    </NavigatorNode>
  </NavigatorNodes>
</Navigator>' AS XML) as xmldata
```

And have been trying queries to get to the information contained within the a1:Condition Node. I've tried queries such as:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
'http://www.ascenttechnology.co.uk/schemas/services' AS a1
,'http://www.ascenttechnology.co.uk/schemas/entities' AS a2
,DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/21/XMLSchema-instance'
)
SELECT 
#xmldata.*
,ref.value('attribute_name[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') as attribute_name
FROM #xmldata
CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/Navigator/NavigatorNodes/NavigatorNode/a1:QueryFilter/a1:ConditionCollection/a1:Condition') T(ref)
```

But they're always coming back blank when I get near the namespaced nodes - I'm able to pull data from the nodes all the way up to `'/Navigator/NavigatorNodes/NavigatorNode'` but then have no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/21/XMLSchema-instance'` but your XML string does even not have a default namespace.

Try

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
  'http://www.ascenttechnology.co.uk/schemas/services' AS a1
, 'http://www.ascenttechnology.co.uk/schemas/entities' AS a2
)
```

Comment: Think this might do the trick - as I'm new to XML namespaces, how would I know if there was a default namespace included?

Comment: @Davin: When there is an `xmlns="…"` declaration at the top level element. Normal namespaces get a prefix assigned, like `xmlns:prefix="namespace-uri"`, the default namespace doesn't.

Comment: this worked fantastically, and learned something new. Thanks!